# Pushing apps to specific folder on iDevice

Tags: ios, profile

I'm using Apple's profile manager to configure a couple dozen iDevices with in house apps.  My question is, is it possible to create a folder on each device with all my apps in it and then push it to the device?  Or can I only push the app and leave it up to the user to organize them into a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. But this is a question to investigate for MDM (mobile device management) solutions/forums. I've used JAMF/Casper in the past and understand that Aerohive might be a solution as well.

But you'll need to be able to manage these devices remotely via a provisioning profile (as you mention), create a policy that does this, and then push out that policy to the iDevices.

That said, this isn't the right forum/resource for this particular question :)